# Write to a named pipe interactively

Tags: fifo

I want to use a named pipe as input for a command line utility I'm writing. I know I can `echo "all work and no play" > ./namedpipe` to write once to the named pipe, but is there a way to do that interactively? That is, as if I'm typing into the stdin of a program or using netcat.

Comment: `cat > namedpipe`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think I actually tried that like 5 times but kept accidentally typing `echo` instead of `cat` without realizing. It works.